# How to dualboot windows, from Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm a Linux newbie. I installed Linux on my laptop, without dual-booting it with Windows, so I think I replaced Windows with Linux. Now I want to reinstall Windows without deleting Ubuntu, dual-booting to the existing Linux and to Windows.
Because I'm a newbie, if possible, can I have a step per step guide?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317

Comment: Question does not make sense: if you replaced Ubuntu with Windows, then you need to reinstall Ubuntu, not reinstall Windows without deleting Ubuntu ( which you already did ).

Answer (score 0):

First, examine the partitions in [gparted](http://gparted.org/) or other tool. If the Windows partition is gone, you will have to completely reinstall Windows.

My experience has been that it is **much** easier to install Linux after Windows has been installed, because doing the converse, installing Windows on a Linux distro will likely damage it.

Therefore, do the following:

1. Back up the HDD before doing anything else. If problems arise, you can revert to a known good installation.
2. Repartition as needed for Windows.
3. Install Windows and check that it works.
4. Create partitions for Linux following a [full, step-by-step guide.](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/)
5. Install Linux to dual-boot with Windows. This should take only a few minutes, as opposed to hours needed for a Windows 10 installation, for example.
6. If your backup of Linux in step 1. is readable, you can restore some files from it. Be careful not to overwrite system files, unless you've got more more experience.